# Should 'dialect' and 'dialects' tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Should [dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialect) and [dialects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialects) tags be merged?

I think so. What's your opinion?

Comment: [Questions tagged with Dialect 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialect2) seem to be talking about [a query dialect used by Microsoft's Indexing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690538%28VS.85%29.aspx). So, disagree with a merge request that includes that tag.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Thanks for your comment, Michael. What should be done, in your opinion, with the other tags mentioned in this question?

Comment: Oh, merging those two tags is a no-brainer. I'm not sure they're very *useful* tags, though.

Comment: It seems those tags are useful. For example, Lisp dialects are used in some enviroments (Scheme, Racket, Common Lisp, etc).

Comment: A rule that makes sense to me: would a person ever subscribe to that tag, as opposed to subscribing to the "Scheme" or "Racket" tags?

Comment: I guess a person who is interested in discussing both Scheme and Racket as programming languages derived from Lisp would use the dialect tag.

Comment: ...and they'd have to deal with all of the C and VB dialect questions they'd get. But: how about removing `dialect2` from your requested merge?

Comment: Yes, they would have to deal with dialect questions related to other programming languages. I have just removed dialect2 from my requested merge.

Comment: What about getting rid of those two tags all together? 43 and 15 questions bare that tag...not very useful...

Comment: The concept of there being multiple "dialects" of a language seems too nebulous to apply a tag to. It involves many different programming languages and environments — in a quick review of the two tags, I see them frequently used to refer to "dialects" of C, SQL, and Lisp, as well as a concept in Hibernate. There's very little relation between these.